# SharePoint 2010 Traffic is going to App Server not WFE

Tags: sharepoint-2010, webserver, web-traffic

Here is my farm configuration (1 app server, 1 web front end and 1 backend db server). I just looked at the IIS logs on App server and WFE and learned all the web traffic is going to APP server and not to the WFE server.

How do I make sure all the traffic needs to hit the WFE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some questions you need to answer:

- What URL are you using to reach your Sharepoint site?
- Does the DNS for the URL point to the WFE?
- Are your Alternate Access Mappings configured correctly?

Comment: That's it. DNS change has been made to go to WFE. Thanks